# TableLayoutPanel having two labels in one cell

Tags: c#

I have 9X6 tableLayoutPanel where I fill some cells with the code below. What I need is sometimes there has to be two labels inside one cell. How can I do that?

```
 void time(String s) {
  //... some algorithm for my code to work 
  for (int i = 0; i < numberPart.Length; i++)
               {
                   number[i] = numberPart[i].ToString(); ;
               }

               for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
               {

                   int j = Convert.ToInt32(number[i]);

                   if (text[i] == "AA")
                   {

             // since i create Panel p everytime i think it just stores the label1 that I put right below and the old one just doesnt display. 

             // what i want is simply inside one cell

        /////////
        label1
        label2
        /////////


                   Panel p = new Panel();
                   Label label1 = new Label();
                   label1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();
                  label1.AutoSize = false;
                  label1.Height = p.Height;  
                   p.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                   p.Controls.Add(label1);
                   tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(p,j,1);
                   }
                    }
```

And the time(String s) is called inside a button click event. So simply put, everytime I click the button a data is pulled and inserted to a label as a text. So I can't add 2nd label inside here that would be pointless. It is not even %100 that there will be 2 labels inside that exact cell.

Comment: You have to create a panel and put the two labels into that panel.  That panel is what goes into the cell.  TableLayoutPanel cells can only have one parent control in them.

Comment: i can't seem to show the labels by doing that. what i do is panel p = new panel(); p.controls.add(label1);   tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(p); @LarsTech

Comment: `p.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;`

Comment: Still can't see the labels. @LarsTech

Comment: Two things.  The label Width?  The Height of the label is the height of the panel, so if you have more rows, you might not see the text.

Comment: ok. managed to see the labels. they seem to work now but the problem is since i create a panel everytime my code runs it still seems to store 1 component inside of it. how can i fix that? @LarsTech

Comment: No idea what you mean.  Maybe update the post with the code as it looks now.

Comment: sorry. edited the text. @LarsTech

Comment: I only see one label in the panel.  Add a second one.  Set each label's Location property to where you want it in the panel.  The height is too high if you want the two labels top and bottom.

Comment: Consider using `FlowLayoutPanel` for the container of the two labels. It will take care of the positioning.

Comment: tried flowlayout with the same code. doesn't do the work. the problem must be that everytime i clicked the button (added additional info to my question) a new panel is created and the first label just moves i suppose. @LarsTech

Comment: Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem you are having. Also include a _precise_, _specific_ description of what that code does and how that's different from what you want it to do. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for additional advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.